# TypeScript with React - TS Error Looping through LI elements

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Looping through a collection of `<li>` elements to remove a specific class, before re-adding the same class to a different `<li>`. Here is the code:

```
useEffect(() => {
   if (dnArrowIdx === undefined) {
      const allLi = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('#srxResultsDiv ul li'));
      const dLi = document.querySelector(`#srxResultsDiv ul li:nth-child(${dnArrowIdx})`);
      if (allLi !== null) {
         allLi.forEach((li) => {
            li.removeClass('liHoverBg');
         });
      }
      if (dLi !== null) dLi.classList.add('liHoverBg');
   }
}, [dnArrowIdx]);
```

The `removeClass` on line `li.removeClass('liHoverBg')` is underlined in red. Error message is:

```
Property 'removeClass' does not exist on type 'Element'.ts(2339)
```

How would I solve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`removeClass` exists in jQuery, but not in JS. To do this in JS, use `classList.remove`:

```
li.classList.remove('liHoverBg');
```

But this is still a very odd thing to do in React. Instead of selecting elements and manipulating them through DOM methods, you should render the elements via *React* and have React either return the element with a `liHoverBg` class or not, eg, something like:

```
{
  results.map((resultText, i) => (
    <li
      className={i === dnArrowIdx + 1 ? 'liHoverBg' : ''}
    >{resultText}</li>
  ))
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that. I am unsure how to implement that advice in this case, because I am responding to a user pressing the downArrow key so many times and adding a colored background (class) to an existing UL with multiple LIs (the overall effect being that the user has highlighted the appropriate LI.)  So I don't see how a map would work here, since the `UL > LI` list already exists on screen. And you're right, I'm  a long-time jQuery user -- so I'll try it again using the correct js method !

Comment: Have the UL component add the listener, and when the user presses the key, change state so that a re-render occurs.